# How to organize storage of calendar dates in MySQL performance wise

Tags: mysql, date, database-performance

I have to store 2 dates for almost every table in database e.g. **tbl_clients tbl_users tbl_employers tbl_position tbl_payments tbl_quiz tbl_email_reminder** etc.

Most times i store "date_created" and "date_modified" sometimes few extra dates.

Whats would be the best approach to storing dates in MySQL database performance wise (site that might have a lot of customers later maybe 500,000+)

**Option 1**: Add 2 columns for dates to each table.

**Option 2**: Create table "**tbl_dates**" exclusively for dates.

I was thinking option 2 will work faster as i only need dates displayed on one specific page e.g. "**report.php**" am i right?

Also how many columns i should put max in "**tbl_dates**" without driving it too slow.

Comment: Store them at the table level. Just make sure you're using native date types. You will create more work for yourself by trying to record dates on a foreign table.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case (a row creation and a row modification timestamp) I would put them in the same table as they relate to. Otherwise, you'll find that the consequent joins you will need will slow down your queries more than the simple approach.

In any case, you don't want to get into the habit of building "general tables" to which many tables can `JOIN` - this is because ideally you would create foreign keys for each relationship, but this won't work if some rows belong to `tbl_clients`, some to `tbl_users`... (etc).

Admittedly your MySQL engine may prevent you from using foreign keys - depending on which one you're using - but (for me at least) the point stands.

Comment: Why not create field `user_id` primary key in table `tbl_users` and then add its value to column `user_id` every other table that relates. <br/>Or have third table that joins `tbl_users` primary id with `tbl_clients` primary id
<br/><br/>i always rather store many tables versus one and go with `LEFT JOIN` i never had issue with that it actually more clear to put data in different tables and join them for me that use same table with 50 columns. Besides join has same speed as any other method you just need to add Index to some fields in database that you use to join.

Comment: There's only value in having a separate table if either (a) only a small subset of your `tbl_users` rows will have creation/modification timestamps, or (b) it is possible for a single row to have multiple creation/modification timestamps. Neither of these possibilities are true, as far as I can tell, so you'd be adding in complexity for no good reason.